# Mail Server with Virus and Spam Protection using CentOS 8

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

I have been working on building a simple mail server using CentOS 8 as the base linux distribution. However, I've hit a issue where I can't get the virus scanner to work correctly with Postfix.

I have installed the following software:

Postfix v3.3.1
Amavisd-new v2.12.0-1
ClamAV v0.102.2-4
Spamassassin v3.4.2-6 (installed by Amavisd-new)
Postgrey v1.37-9

Every seemed to installed okay without errors. The mail server worked as expected before the installation of amavisd-new and ClamAV.

Whenever I send an email I now get the following error in the mail log:

```
May 12 14:02:21 1tmail amavis[1099]: (01099-02) (!)connect to /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock failed, attempt #1: Can't connect to a UNIX socket /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock: No such file or directory
May 12 14:02:23 1tmail amavis[1099]: (01099-02) (!)connect to /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock failed, attempt #1: Can't connect to a UNIX socket /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock: No such file or directory
May 12 14:02:23 1tmail amavis[1099]: (01099-02) (!)ClamAV-clamd: All attempts (1) failed connecting to /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock, retrying (2)
May 12 14:02:29 1tmail amavis[1099]: (01099-02) (!)connect to /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock failed, attempt #1: Can't connect to a UNIX socket /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock: No such file or directory
May 12 14:02:29 1tmail amavis[1099]: (01099-02) (!)ClamAV-clamd av-scanner FAILED: run_av error: Too many retries to talk to /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock (All attempts (1) failed connecting to /var/run/clamd.amavisd/clamd.sock) at (eval 98) line 659.\n
May 12 14:02:29 1tmail amavis[1099]: (01099-02) (!)WARN: all primary virus scanners failed, considering backups
```

the file clamd.sock can't be located anywhere on the server and I am unsure why or where this has gone wrong.

I've followed the following guide for installation: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_8&p=mail&f=7

I've crawled Google and other forums for a fix and can't find any working fixes.

I would appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to get pass this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all packages below are installed, there are probably a package or two you might not need. This is just copied from my notes on my last install and I remember that I had the same issue and I was missing a package and I added it to my notes but I don't remember which one it was exactly.

dnf -y install amavisd-new spamassassin clamav-server clamav-data clamav-update clamav-filesystem clamav clamav-scanner-systemd clamav-devel clamav-lib clamav-server-systemd unzip bzip2 perl-DBD-mysql postgrey re2c sa-update